# PHP What type of object is an anonymous function?

Tags: php, closures, anonymous-function

I know that anonymous functions are objects but what kind of objects are they? E.g

```
function test() {
    return function() {
        return "Hello World!";
    };
}

$test = test();
print gettype($test())
```

Result

```
object
```

I've tried to see if its an instance of a Closure but its not.

```
if($test() instanceof \Closure) {
    print "Hello World!";
}
```

So what object does it inherit from and how can I find that in PHP?

Comment: I think you are looking for http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php

Comment: Anonymous function yield objects of Closure http://docs.php.net/manual/da/class.closure.php

Comment: [`gettype()`](http://php.net/gettype) will only give you the variable type, it won't tell you which class that object is. For that you can use [`get_class()`](http://php.net/get_class). Also what Nerea wrote, it's documented in the manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such function indeed is of type "Closure":

```
<?php
var_dump(function() {
    return "Hello World!";
});
```

The output is:

```
object(Closure)#1 (0) {
}
```

And also the type comparison delivers the expected result:

```
var_dump(function() {
    return "Hello World!";
} instanceof \Closure);
```

This will result in:

```
bool(true)
```